# Multiple Docker images filesystem scan

Tags: security, scripting, docker, filesystems, scanning

I'm trying to identify the most efficient and quickest way to scan multiple Docker images in my environment to determine if specific directory structures exist with each image.

Obviously I can exec into each image on an individual basis and manually check but I'm looking to automate this process.

I cannot think of a way to do this via scripting or api calls and I've not found any vendor software that offers a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can export each image to a tar file

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/

`docker export red_panda > latest.tar`

And then for each tar file, search for that directory

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96410/search-for-a-file-inside-a-tar-gz-file-without-extracting-it-and-copy-the-result

Comment: Thanks kliew. Yeah I did see this one but was concerned about the overhead. I'm expecting hundreds of images running on numerous hosts. As the environment grows I was hoping for something more intelligent.